# FieldPermissions not getting proper results

Tags: soql, permission-sets

**Note**: I am admin User

When I run the Below SOQL I am not getting records don't know why

```
SELECT Id,SobjectType,Field,ParentId,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead,
Parent.Name,Parent.IsOwnedByProfile,Parent.ProfileId,Parent.Profile.Name 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE Field IN ('contact.name')
```

When I run below SOQL I got some other field permission records as well, which mean unnecessary data

```
SELECT Id,SobjectType,Field,ParentId,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead,
Parent.Name,Parent.IsOwnedByProfile,Parent.ProfileId,Parent.Profile.Name 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE Field IN ('contact.name','contact.email')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The query is returning field permissions for `email` across all objects as you have not specified an `SobjectType` in the query.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) takes special note of this:

> Include the field’s parent object when querying FieldPermissions.

And the example below this line in the documentation is the following (note both filters)

```
SELECT Id, SobjectType, Field
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE Field = 'Account.Type' AND SobjectType = 'Account'
```

As such, you should add the SobjectType to your filter and see expected results

```
SELECT 
Id,SobjectType,Field,ParentId 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE Field IN  ('Contact.Name','Contact.Email') AND SobjectType = 'Contact
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, why this soql `SELECT Id,SobjectType,Field,ParentId,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsRead,Parent.Name,Parent.IsOwnedByProfile,Parent.ProfileId,Parent.Profile.Name FROM FieldPermissions WHERE Field IN  ('contact.name')` not returning any data

Comment: I believe it's due to the fact that `Contact.Name` is not something you can configure for FieldPermissions. It's always visible like a system field (Created By, etc).